# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" when pulling information out of a json file

Tags: python, json

I tried pulling som information out of an api: https://services.api.no/api/ordino/frontpage/retten/11-5881f97a8e5dac09a5e6e8a1/wide/legacy

and I got a TypeError: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
import requests
import json

raw = requests.get("https://services.api.no/api/ordino/frontpage/retten/11-5881f97a8e5dac09a5e6e8a1/wide/legacy")
data = raw.json()
art1 = data[1]['layout']['980']['url']
```

I was expecting to get a url returned to `art1`. What does this error mean?

Comment: Do you mean `art1 = data[1]["url"]` ?

Comment: try printing `data[1]`. the order of objects in the list may not be the same as in the response. You may need to search for it in list: `[ob for ob in data if "layout" in ob]`

Comment: Yeah that worked! how did you know that was the correct path @Andrej ? I used this site: https://jsonformatter.org/json-viewer and it told me  data[1]['layout']['980']['url'] was the correct path..